# What is "if (1.0)" checking for?

Tags: javascript

I am adding a piece of tracking code for adwords that is meant to track the amount of the sale. here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1234;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
if (1.0) {
  var google_conversion_value = <?php echo round($order_total['value'],2);?>;
}
var google_conversion_label = "labelid";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

The part I don't understand is the if statement if (1.0)

What is that checking for? why if 1.0? Is this a javascript thing?

Comment: Just somebody's idea. `if(1.0){` is always executed and have no special meaning.

Comment: Did you write the whole snippet by yourself, or you found it somewhere on the web?

Comment: this is from a "plugin" for oscommerce. which is basically just 4 lines of code.

Comment: it's checking if 1.0 is truthy, which is always the case.

Comment: I personally prefer 35.89 as my truthy value, but to each his own i guess.

Comment: `var google_conversion_value = 0;` this line kinda make that whole if block useless

Comment: The doc seems to provide an example with the same error, see https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722021?hl=en, "Dynamic conversion in wrong format". I guess they meant something like `if (aVar === 5000)` instead.

Comment: @igormilla it shouldn't get there because in the if statement it is trying to do something with pure PHP which can not work.

Comment: @igormilla Yes I realized that after posting. I removed it.  I think it would get there as it happens after the php. Anyhow removed it it was unecessary

Comment: Since you're mixing JS with PHP code, my guess is that this should actually have been a serverside `if` or have a dynamic condition `echo`ed into it.

Answer (score 1):

> What is that checking for? why if 1.0? Is this a javascript thing?

```
1.0 === 1; // true, simplification
```

So

```
if (1) // ...
```

And

```
!!1 === true; // true, conversion to boolean
```

So

```
if (true) // ...
```

So it's basically an unnecessary `if`, but it does mean you could "switch off" some code easily when by editing the file

Comment: ok thank you. I guess that makes sense. Couldn't you just as easily comment out the line?

Comment: @Sackling you'd need to also comment out the matching braces

Comment: @PaulS. I meant instead of even writing the if statement so there would be no braces to comment out.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed. This method does have benifits when it comes to entire blocks of code rather than just one line, though.

Comment: yep I can see how now. Thanks for your help!